# Amazon EC2 PublicDnsName

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to get PublicDnsName in amazonEC2?
we can get it from instance using ins.getPublicDnsName() but it get created after a certain time,is there any alternative way to get it?
Or some how get it as soon as it is generated?
for making it wait i did

```
while(flag) {
              time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
              for (Reservation res : ec2.describeInstances().getReservations()) {
                 for (Instance ins : res.getInstances()) {
                     if(ins.getState().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("running") || time == MAX_TIME_FOR_THREAD){                        
                         System.out.println(ins.getPublicDnsName()+"#########"+ins.getInstanceId());
                         flag = false;
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                }                        
          }
```

but inside a run of thread but while I am creating multiple ec2 resources it is returning dns of first up machine multiple times where as i feel it should return different dns address.

Comment: There is no reason to think a newly-created instance *has* an IP right when it is requested.  Instance requests almost surely enter a queue, and Amazon only assigns IPs some (small) time after it begins servicing the request when it comes out.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a slight delay between the instance transitioning to the 'Running' state and the public IP address (and therefore the public DNS name) being allocated - and a longer one if you're also automatically allocating an Elastic IP. It can vary from a second or two up to 5-10 seconds on a busy cluster.

There's nothing you can do but introduce a short delay after detecting the 'Running' state before querying the API - although in your code you're not actually waiting long enough for the instance to get to 'Running' and just hitting MAX_TIME_FOR_THREAD, which is interestingly returning the last DNS name retrieved. This might actually be a small glitch in the API you're using.

In my launcher (written against the .NET API) I have a multithreaded staging loop which launches the instances, then a sleep wait for each to register as 'Running', and then a further sleep wait for the IP address to populate.

Comment: I am getting ip correctly but for one.I am writing everything inside run of thread all object and everything is initialized inside run and i m initializing two thread to invoke but getting same ip after completion of running of two threads. it is returning the public dns of first machine in running state.